# Download and save PDF file via API node.js

Tags: node.js, jspdf

I have a problem to download file from API and save it correctly.
Here is my code:

```js
   const axios = require('axios');
   const fs = require('fs');

    const config = {
        auth: {
         username: //username,
         password: //password,
        },
        headers : {
            Accept: 'application/pdf',
          }
      };
  
      const apiUrl = //api URL;
  
      const pdfFileName = 'getPDF.pdf';
  
      axios.get(apiUrl, config)
      .then(response => {
    
        const pdfData = Buffer.from(response.data);


        fs.writeFileSync(pdfFileName, pdfData);

        console.log(`PDF was downloaded and saved correctly ${pdfFileName}`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error in download a PDF:', error);
      });
```

but response look like this:

��)�������
����_�^���������_�Lfߌ>���S�����?�>-�V���ħA������]2��������?��/��7����W����W������?��k��g�[����?��_�%����(��
��*��
����5�,����~�5�
�����+| ����'����������_���M�g���k�����������������?��!q����э���ǟ�T�.?�]�1��ٟ����
���� _����
��F5��3��AQ����u��ƿ�fc���*�_�(����.����l��y��G�B������͙��?� ��~�����\���c_��?���D�
��_��k�6g�<�肯����?��!q����э���ǟ�TW��Q@�E���B��(���͙���� ���?�_����ػ�
��V~��G���Z��k�

And the created PDF file is an empty file.

I have tried also set encoding  in `Buffer.from` but still almost the same.

Have any body some advice how to correctly save the PDF file?

Thank you very much!!

I tried this if there is a problem in encoding but still the same problem:

```js
const pdfData = Buffer.from(response.data, "base64");
```

also

```js
fs.writeFileSync(pdfFileName, pdfData), {
        encoding: "base64",
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: apiUrl,
  responseType: 'stream', // Set the response type to 'stream' to handle 
  binary data
 }).then((response) => {
    const pdfStream = fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath);
    response.data.pipe(pdfStream);
    pdfStream.on('finish', () => {
      console.log('PDF file downloaded successfully.');
    });

  pdfStream.on('error', (err) => {
     console.error('Error downloading PDF:', err);
   });
   }).catch((error) => {
   console.error('Error making the API request:', error);
 });
```